# Enviar formulário como variável em javascript externo

Tags: javascript

Quero receber valor de uma Variável vinda de um formulário, e que essa variável apareça em alerta em outra página.

Meu código é simples porém não está funcionando.

Primeiro o código do Index

```
<head>
<title>Formulário para gerar variável</title>

<script language="text/JavaScript" src="newtag.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="_log.html">
Digite seu nome:<br/>
<input type="text" name="texto" id="txt"/>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="advice001()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Código do Javascript (código separado)

```
var texto = document.getElementById("txt"); 

function advice001(){
  alert("Seu texto",texto);
}
```

E, por último, o resultado para ser visível na barra de Alerta

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="newtag.js"></script>


<title>Resultado</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<input type="button" value="Aperte aqui para ver seu nome" onclick="advice001()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Conto com sua ajuda! Obrigado!

Comment: essa linha está "pegando" só o elemento, para pegar o conteúdo use: `var texto = document.getElementById("txt").value`. Segundo, mova essa linha para dentro da function e antes do `alert`, porque precisa ver o conteúdo na hora que clicar. Já para ler em outra página, pesquise sobre method "GET" e "query string"

Comment: Olá. Tentando Inserir dentro da function, não ativa o alert e também o ´´´var texto = document.getElementById("txt").value´´´ não está recebendo.

Answer (score 0):

Você irá precisar armazenar o valor do `input` `txt`, do jeito que você fez não irá funcionar, pois o `javascripit` é uma linguagem Front-end, a variável texto e o input não existem no `_log.html`. Mas para realizar isso você pode usar O armazenamento da web HTML fornece dois objetos para armazenar dados no cliente:

- `window.localStorage` - armazena dados sem data de validade
- `window.sessionStorage` - armazena dados para uma sessão (os dados são perdidos quando a guia do navegador é fechada)

Usa-se `setItem(item, value)` para denominar um item e `getItem(item)` para ''pegar'' o item. Para remover o item usa-se `removeItem(item)` e para apagar o Storage inteiro usa `clear()`.

E para realizar tudo isso em uma `function`, você utilizaria:

Para `sessionStorage`:

Código do Javascript (código separado) *(newTag.js)*

```js
function advice001(){
    if (window.location.href.includes('index.html'){
  sessionStorage.setItem('nome', document.getElementById("txt").value) 
  alert(sessionStorage.getItem('nome'));
    } else if (window.location.href.includes('_log.html') {
        alert(sessionStorage.nome)
    }
}
```

e Para `localStorage`:

Código do Javascript (código separado) *(newTag.js)*

```js
function advice001(){

    if (window.location.href.includes('index.html'){
        localStorage.setItem('nome', document.getElementById("txt").value)
alert(localStorage.nome)
    } else if (window.location.href.includes('_log.html'){
    alert(localStorage.getItem('nome')); 
}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: essa é uma solução mas, como o html tem o input numa tag form com action, faria muito mais sentido "postar" o código para a prroxima pagina, sem precisar armazenar o valor. Além disso, com o exemplo de `sessionStorage` se executar esse código uma vez e tentar fazer novamente só vai exibir sempre o primeiro nome que foi armazenado

Comment: Perdão. Obrigado mas tampouco compreendo o localStorage.E aos códigos, não gera um alert, mesmo testado na própria página

Comment: Olha o melhor método seria com o Storage acompanhado do window.location.href (vou editar a minha resposta)